# Corrigir erro de XSS apontado pelo Site Blindado - ASP Clássico

Tags: asp, xss

Administro um site que tem o selo do site blindado, recentemente recebi um e-mail do site blindado dizendo que seu core havia mudado e os novos scans poderiam identificar novos erros.

Conforme previsto, foram identificados novos erros que foram devidamente corrigidos, exceto erros de XSS em uma única página.

A página em questão é:
http://cardios.com.br/noticias_detalhes.asp?idNoticia=523&IdSecao=48&IdTipoNoticia=14

E o erro apontado é:

> Cross-Site Scripting vulnerability found. This is a reflected XSS vulnerability, detected in an alert that was an immediate response to the injection. Injectable request #: 2 Injected item: GET: IdSecao Injection value: `>"><sVg/OnLOaD=alert(14417575.00347)>` Detection value: alert(14417575.00347)

O problema é:
Não consigo reproduzir a falha, ela parece não estar ocorrendo para mim. Mas o site blindado continua apontando o erro.

Como resolver?

Comment: Poste o código para análise.

Comment: Posso postar, mas o código é bem extenso.
Mas, ao colocar o "Injection value" na URL, junto ao campo desprotegido "IdSecao" deveria aparecer um alert na tela, não? Este alert não aparece. Se vc conseguisse me ajudar apenas a mostrar esse alert acusado pelo Site Seguro, eu conseguiria resolver. Eu apenas não consigo reproduzir a falha.